# Recursive function to going through each embedded schema field in a schema to reach a leaf data field

Tags: tridion

I have a schema in Tridion which have embedded schema fields which may further have embedded fields in there.

I want to reach final leaf field so that I can assign some value to it. For that I want to write recursive function which loop through each and every field until it reaches a final field.

I am implementing using the Core Service in SDL Tridion 2011

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


namespace Loading_Utility
{
    public partial class TST : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Fields obj = new Fields();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService> factory =
            new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>("wsHttp_2011"))
            {
                ISessionAwareCoreService client = factory.CreateChannel();
                var schemaFields = client.ReadSchemaFields("tcm:202-2242-8", true, new ReadOptions());
                ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, "tcm:202-638-2");
                var fields = Fields.ForContentOf(schemaFields);
                component.Schema.IdRef="tcm:202-2242-8";
            }
        }
        public void fieldRecursion(Field field)
        {
            //var getFields = fields;
            if (field.GetType() == typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
            {
                // code for checking further if field is embedded or not


                //Field newField = field.GetSubFields().GetFieldElements( new ItemFieldDefinitionData() as Field)
                //fieldRecursion(recursiveField);
            }
            //string fieldName = recursiveField.Name;
            //fields[fieldName] = "HI";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide the code you've tried and the specific issue you ran into?

Comment: @ Nickoli please see my edited code...
I am trying to write a recursive function which recurse through each field in schema untill it reach final leaf field which is not embedded so that i can assign data to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I don't have the solution you are looking for, I see you're using the core service, personally I prefer to get hold of the Component XML (Component.Content) and parse/manipulate it as I need.  Perhaps if you can paste the XML here I can drop it into one of my sample core service projects and send you a solution back?

In the event that doesn't help you, i've had a look at the api, and this should help you get going in the right path.  Perhaps once you have a solution you could paste it here?

```
public void RecurseEmbeddedFields(SchemaFieldsData schemaFields)
{
    foreach (ItemFieldDefinitionData field in schemaFields.Fields)
    {
        if (field.GetType() == typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
        {
            // check if this field contains more embedded fields
            // if it does recurse
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks johnwinter .. Please see my  edited code i got stuck wher i commented

Comment: @ johnwriter can you add the code at below location:
// check if this field contains more embedded fields
            // if it does recurse
i AM not able to get that.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, I felt a bit guilty about not helping, but I still stand by my view that this is not a Tridion-related question and that you should try getting some more experience with general development practices.

Here's an example of how to load the Component's content, then read it recursively using Xml:

Xml of the component:

```xml
<Content xmlns="uuid:02395f72-acef-44e8-9c35-ff8c9f380251">
    <EmbeddedSchema1>
        <SomeField>Hello</SomeField>
        <EmbeddedSchema2>
            <ATextField>There</ATextField>
        </EmbeddedSchema2>
    </EmbeddedSchema1>
</Content>
```

Core Service code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("wsHttp_2011");
    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();

    ComponentData component = (ComponentData)client.Read("tcm:5-3234", readOptions);
    Console.WriteLine("Find fields recursively");

    XmlDocument content = new XmlDocument();
    content.LoadXml(component.Content);
    SchemaData schema = (SchemaData)client.Read(component.Schema.IdRef, readOptions);
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    ns.AddNamespace("content", schema.NamespaceUri);

    foreach (XmlElement node in content.SelectNodes("content:*", ns))
    {
        ReadContentRecursively(node, ns);
    }
    client.Close();
}
private static void ReadContentRecursively(XmlElement node, XmlNamespaceManager ns)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText))
    {
        foreach (XmlNode innerNode in node)
        {
            if(innerNode is XmlText)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Node " + node.Name + " with value \"" + innerNode.Value + "\"");
            }
        }
    }
    if(node.SelectNodes("content:*", ns).Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlElement childNode in node.SelectNodes("content:*", ns))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found Field: " + childNode.Name);
            ReadContentRecursively(childNode, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how ReadContentRecursively calls itself?

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have to create a new component thats why i cant use that xml approach

Comment: What is your question then? I'm a bit confused. First you ask how to loop through fields, and now you ask how to create a component? Component content _is_ XML, there's absolutely nothing stopping you from using this approach.

Comment: @ Nuno... ok i will clarify u
I have only one thing with me i.e. schema id
I have to create component on the basis of that schema id ....and want to give default values to it
I have to create component xml rather than getting it from tridion

My motive is to create a component in tridion using schema id , i dont have any component previously in tridion so i cant read its xml frm there.

Comment: I am sure I can, but have no time now. Maybe later today